# "Insufficient Storage Space" problem with Titanium Root, preventing backup

Tags: backup, sd-card

I'm in a pickle I have no idea how to fix. I turned off the often suggested "Mount Namespace Separation" option in SU, and it doesn't work with this issue. I uninstalled/ reinstalled Titanium Root, no luck. Restarted the device after toggling off the namespace option, no dice. I have no idea what to do. It's not entirely a loss, as some games will backup just fine, just one brand is being stubborn. The Flutter series, where you collect butterflies and such. They're huge files, and it backs them up for a long while before hitting the memory space issue. It is confirmed and set to the Titanium Backup file on my SD card, where I backed up other games. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what happened, or how, but I had to use a different browsing method for Titatium Backup. Even though I had selected sdcard/titaniumbackup (example), it wouldn't work even though it was listed as an option. I believe I had to use a different backup storage option, in which it showed me a list. After I selected "SD" from this new interface, it fixed everything and now the weird games will backup.
I apologize for this idiocy of mine. Since only one group of games were acting up, I thought it was something of specific conflicting data.

Answer (score 0):

Move some of your saved games to the computer to increase the space of your sdcard. Once you finish copying the rest you are joining it in parts.